# What mplayer.exe file to use for linux

Tags: mono, debian, mplayer

I wrote a small program in mono to play a video using mplayer. To run the video i used the mplayer.exe for window, now i want to use this program in debian.

Does someone know what i should us instead of the window mplayer.exe.

thanx

Comment: there is no standard video player app in linux. closest might be videolan, but availability is not guaranteed.

Comment: actually i embedded the mplayer.exe in my app, so i could play a video. So i was wondering if there is a nother mplayer.exe i could use to embed in debian

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mplayer on Windows, then you could just use mplayer on Linux. You can install it with `aptitude install mplayer` or `aptitude install mplayer2`. On Linux of course it won't have `.exe` as part of its name. (I'm assuming when you say you're using mplayer you mean that, and not Windows Media Player. Windows Media Player isn't available for Linux.)

There are a bunch of other choices. Your best bet for cross-platform is probably VLC, but you also have Totem, Xine, etc. You can find the Debian-packaged ones using `apt-cache search`, e.g., `apt-cache search video player | sort | less` gives a lot of things (including some things that aren't video players, unfortunately).

Comment: mplayer is embedded in my application. i dont need to install it. The mplayer.exe file is in my project map. because the exe was for windows only i was wondering if someone knows what file mplayer file i could use in debian